# Docker running Node exits immediately, how can I get access?

Tags: docker

I took over a project where a company internal website is running in a Docker container. I did some changes to the code and now whenever I start/restart the container it immediately exits. I assume this is because there is some can of error with the code execution in the Node service inside the container. But how can I fix this if I cannot attach a console to the container to make changes in the code?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the entrypoint so you can just get to a shell in the container? `docker run -it --entrypoint sh ...`, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Awesome, I start to like docker :)
Just create an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: (If the Dockerfile ends with something like `CMD npm run start` and not `ENTRYPOINT`, you can `docker run --rm -it your-image sh` without the `--entrypoint` option.)

Comment: Do you have the source code of the app?

Comment: You mean the node app running inside the container? The problem I currently have is that the solution proposed by @DavidMaze starts a new container, but that one is not up to date. I'm now trying to copy out the probably corrupted files from my container, fix them and move them back in.